# SimpleXML - Read from unknown element-name

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

Let's assume an Android device receives a XML file like this:

```
<List>
    <ListItem>
        <Element1>foo</Element1>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <Element2>another foo</Element2>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <Element3>foo foo</Element3>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <Element4>foooo</Element4>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <Element5>foo five</Element5>
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

As you can see, the element-name for a listitem is always the same. So I can create a class for the SimpleXMLFramework like this:

```
@Root(name = "ListItem")
public class ListItem
{
    @Element(name = ?????)
    String Element;
}
```

And in the end I want to use it like this:

```
...

    @ElementList(name = "List")
    List<ListItem> Items;

...
```

So.. my problem is, I don't know the name of the elements. As you can see above, the name changes in every ListItem. Is there a way I can say "yes, there is a element, but the name does not care!" ?

Thanks & regards